# Change date format from YYYYQQ or YYYY to mm/dd/yyyy

Tags: r

I have a column of data with two different formats: yyyyqq and yyyyy. I want to reformat the column to mmddyyyyy.

Whenever I use the following command `as.Date(as.character(x), format = "%y")` the output is yyyy-12-03. I cannot get any other combination of `as.Date` to work.

I'm sure this is a simple fix, but how do I do this?

Comment: Those are periods, not dates. Which one of the 90 days in a quarter, or 365 days in a year do you want? The first one? Last one? You'll have to specify the missing data

Comment: Besides, dates are binary values, not strings in a specific format. Don't store them as strings. `mmddyyyyy` is a particularly bad idea as it's unsortable and *completely unexpected*. Nothing prevents an application from parsing this as `yyyymmdd`, a far more common format. Use the `date` type instead, and format the date value when you display it

Comment: `the output is yyyy-12-03` that's as logical as any other value, and arguably exactly what you asked - lacking any other information, `as.Date` assumed the current date should be used. That date can be formatted any way you want when displaying it or exporting it to a file with `format(thatDate, "%m%Y%d")`.

Comment: What is the expected output for an input? Please give an example.

Comment: And once again, don't use that format. Whenever unseparated date literals are used, they're assumed to be in the `YYYYMMDD` format, not a modified US-only format. Users outside the US won't understand that *at all*. Either use the ISO8601 format, or let R use the current user's locale settings to produce something that makes sense to them. Or specify the locale. Messing date formats has cause *significant* problems - before COVID-19 the big IT news of 2020 was that [Lloyds and RBS shut down for a few days](https://www.theregister.com/2020/01/02/lloyds_outage/) due to Y2K issues. In 2020.

Comment: And [The Spanish family wrongly accused of child pornography due to a mistake reading a date](https://english.elpais.com/spanish_news/2020-09-08/the-spanish-family-wrongly-accused-of-child-pornography-due-to-a-mistake-reading-a-date.html)

Answer (score 1):

Using the following assumptions:

```
2021 <- 2021-01-01
2021Q1 <- 2021-01-01
2021Q2 <- 2021-04-01
2021Q3 <- 2021-07-01
2021Q4 <- 2021-10-01
```

You can use the following:

```
as.Date(paste(substr(x, 1, 4), 3*as.numeric(max(substr(x, 6, 6),1))-2, "1", sep = "-"))
```

Edit: You can wrap this in a `format(..., "%m%d%Y)` but as already said in the comments I would not recommend it.

Comment: This is the solution I was looking for. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a function which translates to the first (if frac=0) or last (if frac=1) date of the period. First append a 01 (first of the period) or 04 (last of the period) to the end of the input.  That puts them all in yyyyqq format possibly with junk at the end.  Then yearqtr will convert to a yearqtr object ignoring any junk.  Then convert that to a Date object.  as.Date.yearqtr uses the same meaning for frac. Finally format it as a character string in mm/dd/yyyy format.

(One alternative is to replace the format(...) line with chron::as.chron() in which case it will render in the same manner, since the format specified is the default for chron, but be a chron dates object which can be manipulated more conveniently, e.g. it sorts chronologically, than a character string.)

```
library(zoo)

to_date <- function(x, frac = 1) x |>
  paste0(if (frac == 1) "04" else "01") |>
  as.yearqtr("%Y%q") |>
  as.Date(frac = frac) |>
  format("%m/%d/%Y")

# test data
dd <- data.frame(x = c(2001, 2003, 200202, 200503)) 

transform(dd, first = to_date(x, frac = 0), last = to_date(x, frac = 1))
```

giving:

```
       x      first       last
1   2001 01/01/2001 12/31/2001
2   2003 01/01/2003 12/31/2003
3 200202 04/01/2002 06/30/2002
4 200503 07/01/2005 09/30/2005
```